# SSH password entered too many times Connection refused

Tags: ssh, password

I tried connecting to my new installed Ubuntu 12 server via SSH and I was asked for my password. (I had used "myusername@ipadress" to connect)

After entering the **right** password a few times (with no luck; access denied) I started getting an error directly telling me that the connection was refused without asking me for a password anymore.

It seems like I have managed to blacklist myself. It has been like this for about 2 hours now, is there a quick solution for this?

Comment: How do you install the SSH Server?

Comment: Anyway, if you don't install ssh-server yet, install `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`,  Ping the server,  if your server is remote may be the ssh `Port 22` blocked by your ISP or something. So, you should change the  port number from 22 to something else  editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Aaaaahhh, *^*^¨'. Well i believed i told my server to install it during the initial installation of Ubuntu server. I ran the install command now and it installed. Logged in successfully now... So how do i end this post?

Comment: :) by accepting my answer. But don't delete your comment, it will help peoples who run the same situation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't installed ssh-server yet, you need to install it by running:

`sudo apt-get install openssh-Server`,

You may also need to check if the default SSH `Port 22` is open on your Router/Firewall. You may also need to change the default port under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Nice answer, it reminded me that i need to open port 22 in my router as well.

Comment: Same problem after a fresh install Ubuntu 18 minimal client + Virtualmin. Ubuntu 18 minimal client nor Virtualmin are instaling sshd, only ssh client.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a virtual server from ionos together with plesk panel. The same as the operator is stating happend to me: I entered a wrong password three times and the result was 'connection refused' errors on subsequential requests.

Solving the problem was rather easy: On plesk/home you got 'ip address banning'. Visiting those tab it was easy to unban my ip-address.

Afterwards I could login with correct password.

Comment: @David Plesk is a well known UI config tool for webservers on Linux systems. I deleted Plesk anyway and stay with Terminal based configuration.